# Action Script navigateToURL not working with stage3d

Tags: actionscript-3, stage3d, navigatetourl

this simple code is not working for me :

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnClick);

protected function OnClick(e:MouseEvent)
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.stackoverflow.com"), "_blank");
}
```

later i want url to open from flascc but that can be easily done if this works,
if this is because of security reason then is there any other way to do this? i saw in game called decision 2 their urls work even in debug version flash player + in all browsers. so there must be some other way to do this if navigateToURL dosent work.

Comment: Is the event handler method getting executed? There's no security issues with using navigateToURL(). Are you using starling, which has its own versions of the event class(es)?

Comment: yes event is getting executed and i get this error in standalone flash player 11 when clicked : SecurityError: Error #2028: Local-with-filesystem SWF file file:///F|/flascc/Game.swf cannot access Internet URL http://www.stackoverflow.com. but no errors in any browser and i am not using starling just using c++ with console.as as AS3 frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the folder f:\flascc (or all disk f:) to the flash trusted locations in the [security panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) (you can also open this panel by the right click on any swf opened in the browser)

Comment: This works on standalone player now but not on any browser, i added same folder in browsers security panel.
Does this mean i have to tell every user to add folders in trusted locations?

Comment: No, it's only local requirements for developer. Via http this error will not occur.

Comment: I added this to localhost and it does work except it always has to be called in click event and also wondering how decision 2 game did it they don't even require permission to open links on local too.

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment, what are you wondering about, and do you still have some issues related to the topic?

Comment: no there are no issues now, its just that navigateToURL must be always called in click event for example if you call it in added to stage event it doesn't work and wondering about game named decision 2 which have links that work on my standalone flash player and browser locally without adding location in security panel.

Comment: links also can works within htmlText in textfield (_a_ tag) they still require click but you haven't to create handler and call _navigateToURL_ manually. Locally they always require adding to trusted folder since flash player 9. If your issue solved please accept the answer.